# Google Apps in Domain

Tags: google-apps, user-registration

I'm thinking about using google apps for my website so I can use the email service, calendar to display events, and docs so that the user can upload files and it will be saved to google docs. But I had a question about pricing, i've been reading on the website but i can't seem to answer my question. For the free version of google apps it says maximum users 10, what does that mean? Who are users? Do they mean a maximum of 10 people can register for an account on your website and use the apps?

I'll be having a few hundred registering so if that's what maximum users means, then can someone recommend an alternative, i mainly only need the docs (email would be nice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum users means that you'll be able to create only 10 users - email addresses (aliases are not count).

Comment: so if I just have one email address (email from the website: email@domain.com) then that counts as 1 user?

Comment: yes, even if you want to use only docs, you'll have to create email address for each user, they will use it as a login for google docs.

Comment: Well when they register they have to supply their email address. Okay so, just to make sure we're clear, even if a 100 people register and all of them upload docs to google, the number of users will only be 1 since the website only has 1 email address

Comment: not sure what you mean. as an administrator you supply email address, but than you register every user, user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com, etc. so now you have 2 users. all 100 can use one account but than you missing the main point of Google apps, collaboration between users and email server.

Comment: oh no i think we're misunderstanding. I just want to use the email server to send registered users emails (password recovery, notifications, etc). Everyone has to register with their own email address. Like user1 will register with his hotmail address, user2 registers with her yahoo address. I will then use the site address, admin@domail.com to send them all emails.

Comment: so based on my use, does that mean there will only be 1 user? Also, if the users upload it goes into google docs, but will users of different email address (hotmail, yahoo) be able to upload to google docs?